# How to set bootstrap menu a item visible on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that my client needs to set the cart menu item visible beside the menu button when is on mobile device but I don't know what is the better way to do this. Does anyone of you have any tips  ? I appreciate in advance. Bellow is an image of the item highlighted in yellow that I want to set visible :
[image]

Comment: By adding class "col-visible-xs col-visible-sm col-hidden-md col-hidden-lg"

Comment: you can add another cart button beside the mobile menu , make it hidden and use `@media queries` to show it on mobile

Answer (score 0):

By adding following class you can hide it in big screen and show in mobile.

```
col-visible-xs col-visible-sm col-hidden-md col-hidden-lg
```

For hidding in big screen use following class

```
col-hidden-md col-hidden-lg
```

Showing in small screen use following class

```
col-visible-xs col-visible-sm
```

Comment: Or just `col-hidden-md col-hidden-lg`?

Comment: @m.spyratos For hidding in large screen we will use "col-hidden-md col-hidden-lg" For showing it in small screen we will use "col-visible-xs col-visible-sm"

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at [Bootstrap's Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) documentation. You can use the `hidden-` or `visible-` classes.

To hide on desktops add the following classes to your element:

```
hidden-md hidden-lg
```

To hide on mobile use:

```
hidden-xs hidden-sm
```

---

Here's a [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lujb4wx5/embedded/result/).

Comment: you have copied my answer. Please stop copying others answers.

Comment: @J.Shabu I see you have updated yours with my code. I'm happy you found my answer useful.

Comment: I don't like your attitude. If you are not satisfied with my answer report/downvote it. Because you posted an answer first, does not mean that others cannot post their answers. I believe my answer can be helpful, plus it uses the `hidden` class, not the `col-hidden` that you use (first time I see this class to be honest). For me `col-hidden` doesn't even work.

Answer (score -1):

You could search something for this in jquery and showing and hiding blocks. a very simple way would be to use media queries in CSS. It isn't the best solution but it is the easiest one.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
  .shopping-cart {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .shopping-cart {
    display: block
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to close off both of your media's, don't forgot your curly brackets!